# in which cases should be used certain types of IoC frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I know that there are many IoC frameworks in .net ( They are: Ninject, Unity, Castle Windsor   , Structure Map ) They also used to same goal - resolving dependencies. But i don't understand in which cases should be used certain framework! they are almost similar. Who can simply explain the main differences?

Comment: [IoC Container Benchmark - Performance comparison](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) has performance and features comparison tables for 20+ products and keep them up-to-date. It recommends [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each and every one has a [fatal flaw](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=225701475&dept_url=/windows/).

On a more serious note they surely do essentially the same thing, but differ in implementation details, conventions, performance, auxiliary features and suggested usecases.

I don't think that you should really sweat picking *the* IoC container. Stick to one you're used to and continue with your core functionality.

Comment: Thank you countryman, Can you give me link to some article about essential differences in  russian language?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your needs. Some containers are very mature or have a big community. Others are feature rich or very fast. It all depends on what you need, but the problem is that you only know this when you already did one or two projects using DI and DI containers. And still, when you're architecture changes the requirements for your container will change.

So whatever container you pick, be prepared to change your container. This means, stick to the Dependency Injection pattern and prevent yourself from letting application code have a direct dependency on the container (a pattern which is called [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

DI/IOC or whatever you want to call it is a means to an end - not the end in itself. Find one you like and that does everything you need and go with it (until you're told to use something else).

I rolled my own based on StructureMap and probably learned more doing that than actually using any of the others.

Comment: I often using Unity but i was try to use Castle windsor - and i think it more difficult to set up, it need more classes to configure, and i think that ninject almost same as Unity a little bit  different sintax. It was differences which i found for me.

Comment: Without a doubt, certain ones do limit or to some extent drive how you have to write your code. For example, the factory based ones I've looked at seem to enforce a 1-->1 mapping between an interface and a concretion. Not a problem in itself for green field development but if you're trying to retrofit DI to an existing solution, you may have a number of concretions based on an interface